# Why is my background gradient extending past the border on Mac and ios?

Tags: html, ios, css, macos

I have a carousel of rounded images with a gradient over them, so that white text can be easily read when placed over the image.  Occasionally, the gradient doesn't follow the border-radius and extends in it's default square shape past the border.  I actually haven't been able to recreate this on my own Mac, but one of my designers has said that this happens quite often to her on her Mac and iPhone:

[image]

Here's the CSS I'm using for the image and gradient:

```
.carousel-image-container {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 6px solid white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .carousel-image-container img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .carousel-image-container::after {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(69, 72, 77, 0.07) 5%, rgba(69, 72, 77, 0.1) 8%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
        margin-top: -300px;
        height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
        content: '';
    }
```

Has anybody run into this before/can anybody help me make it not happen anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're applying `border-radius` only to your `<img>` but not to the `:after` pseudo-element.

```
.carousel-image-container:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

should fix your problem. If it doesn't you'll need to provide a [mcve] so I could actually inspect what you have.

Another possible fix is:

```
.carousel-image-container{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's probably it, huh?  I added the change and emailed my designer to see if it's still happening - but this is totally the answer!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
Add border-radius also .carousel-image-container::after, Like

.carousel-image-container::after {
border-radius:50%;
}
```